# Why MYSQL AND oparator not working when trying to extract data in same column?

Tags: mysql

I want to select the paperId from my database using tagName - 
this is the query I used to try and do this.

```sql
SELECT * FROM papertag WHERE tagName="cs" AND tagName="cs202";
```

and this was the result.

```
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

this is my *papertag* table.

```
+-------+--------------+-------------------------+-----+
| tagId | paperId      | tagName                 | des |
+-------+--------------+-------------------------+-----+
|    37 | yohan1779762 | cs 202                  |     |
|    38 | yohan1779762 | Yohan Rashmitha         |     |
|    39 | yohan1779762 | cs                      |     |
|    40 | yohan1779762 | cs202                   |     |
|    41 | yohan1779763 | This is my first upload |     |
|    42 | yohan1779763 | Yohan Rashmitha         |     |
|    43 | yohan1779763 | cs                      |     |
|    44 | yohan1779763 | cs202                   |     |
|    45 | yohan1779763 | end                     |     |
|    46 | yohan1779764 | simple set              |     |
|    47 | yohan1779764 | Yohan Rashmitha         |     |
|    48 | yohan1779764 | example                 |     |
+-------+--------------+-------------------------+-----+
```

When a user enters '*cs cs201*' in the search bar, I want to display only papers which have both of these tags.

Comment: You can't have a column which is equal to cs and cs202 at the same time.

Comment: `tagName` cannot be equal to `cs` and `cs 202` __at the same time__. You probably want `OR` instead of `AND`.

Comment: actually this is my scenario. when user enter in cs cs201 in the search bar, i want to display only papers which have both of this tags. tags means user input. (in this cs and cs202)

Comment: Edit your question to explain what you want and you should get an answer with GROUP BY, HAVING and COUNT() that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on clarification in comments:
 *I want to display only papers which have both of this tags.*

You should select all rows that have at least one of the required tags. Then group them by their paperId and filter results where number of selected rows match the number of required tags.

```
SELECT `paperId`
  FROM `papertag`
  WHERE `tagName` IN ('cs', 'cs202')
  GROUP BY (`paperId`)
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Note: when using `GROUP BY` you should only select columns mentioned in `GROUP BY` claues or apply an aggregate function on the columns. MySQL will allow you to select column that is not part of `GROUP BY` clause but it's value is not well defined and it might lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 4):

Use Mysql In function to get both values

```
SELECT * FROM papertag WHERE tagName IN ('cs','cs202') GROUP BY (`paperId`);
```

Comment: thank you. I tried this.SELECT * FROM papertag WHERE tagName IN ('cs','cs202');
+-------+--------------+---------+-----+
| tagId | paperId      | tagName | des |
+-------+--------------+---------+-----+
|    39 | yohan1779762 | cs      |     |
|    40 | yohan1779762 | cs202   |     |
|    43 | yohan1779763 | cs      |     |
|    44 | yohan1779763 | cs202   |     |
+-------+--------------+---------+-----+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec) . this is the result. but i want only get which paperId have both of this tags(cs,cs202) only once. this case it gives two times.

Comment: @YohanRashmitha use GROUP BY tagName

Answer (score 1):

Either you can use **IN** operator

```
SELECT * FROM papertag WHERE tagName IN ("cs","cs202");
```

Or can use **OR** operator

```
SELECT * FROM papertag WHERE tagName ="cs" OR tagName= "cs202";
```

Comment: thank. you. but actually this is my scenario. when user enter in cs cs201 in the search bar, i want to display only papers which have both of this tags. tags means user input. (in this cs and cs202). if i use OR oparator i think i cant do this.